# How to store the NSArray with customized Object?

Tags: objective-c, io, storage

I have an NSMutableArray, if this is store string, I can read, and write it successfully, using this method.

```
[array writeToFile:m_sApplicationPlistPath atomically:YES];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:m_sApplicationPlistPath];
```

but if my Array add something which is not a simple string, for example, I add a special Object to the array, like this:

```
[array addObject:[[SpecialObject alloc] init]];
```

I find that I can't read back the special object, how can I solve it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work by using methods defined in the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol to convert the instances of your custom class to instances of `NSDictionary` before you write them. You could do a similar conversion after reading the plist file back in to recreate the objects.

Here's an example that converts an array of instances of a custom `Book` class to an array of dictionaries, using the `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` method declared in `NSKeyValueCoding` (and implemented by `NSObject`, so all objects inherit this behavior):

```
+ (NSArray *)dictionariesFromBooks:(NSArray *)books
{
    NSMutableArray *bookDicts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[books count]];

    for (Book *currBook in books)
    {
        NSDictionary *currDict = [currBook dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[Book keys]];
        [bookDicts addObject:currDict];
    }

    return bookDicts;
}
```

Similarly, here's a method that populates instances of `Book` using the `NSKeyValueCoding` method `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`

```
+ (NSArray *)booksFromDictionaries:(NSArray *)bookDicts
{
    NSMutableArray *books = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[bookDicts count]];

    for (NSDictionary *currDict in bookDicts)
    {
        Book *currBook = [[Book alloc] init];
        [currBook setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:currDict];
        [books addObject:currBook];
        [currBook release];
    }

    return books;
}
```

With a little work, this can be made to cascade to nested custom objects. For example, if `Book` contained a nested `Author` instance, you could override `NSKeyValueCoding` methods such as `setValue:forKey:` and `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` to convert the instance on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the NSCoding protocol. (encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder)

If you still cannot use the method writeToFile:atomically: then you have to serialize the NSArray to get data, and then write it to an file.

```
NSData *data = NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:theArray];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't do that because [NSArray writeToFile:atomically:] method makes use of property lists, which are only available for certain data types (NSString, NSData, NSArray or NSDictionary).

In order for you to write the array to a file you can make SpecialObject comply to [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and then save the array using -[[NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) archiveRootObject:toFile:] using the array as root object.

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

If the array’s contents are all property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects), the file written by this method can be used to initialize a new array with the class method arrayWithContentsOfFile: or the instance method initWithContentsOfFile:. This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.